# apche http-ssl.conf "allow from" doesn't work with localhost but works with local ip

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm tring to allow access only from local host to local directory via apache.
In httpd-ssl.conf I declared the following:

```
<Location /uploads/>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Allow from 127.0.0.1 or Allow from localhost doesn't work.
only Allow from IP_ADRESS works

what could cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the python script I used with PUT https request.
I used there the url for the server and not localhost, the script ran from localhost.
when I changed the url from www.example.com:8080 to localhost:8080
the probelm was solved.